# ArcGIS Javascript API WFS Layer with Ramp Renderer

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wfs, rendering

I am trying to implement the setRenderer method of the [WFS Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/wfslayer-amd.html) object using a simple renderer with a color ramp using the [setColorInfo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/simplerenderer-amd.html#setcolorinfo) method of the SimpleRenderer class.

This works fine if I use a feature layer derived from and ArcServer instance, as in this example: [Color ramp with rotation and proportional symbols | ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.17](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/renderer_class_breaks_proportional_rotation.html)   but does not work for my WFS. Oddly, if I use a class breaks renderer to achieve a similar effect, it works fine. I have found nothing in the docs to suggest that only some renderers work with a WFS.

I have isolated the problem with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Class breaks with rotation and proportional symbols</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #border-container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
<script>
  require([
    "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend",
    "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/Color", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
"esri/layers/WFSLayer",


    "esri/layers/LabelLayer", "esri/symbols/TextSymbol", "esri/symbols/Font", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", "esri/config",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, FeatureLayer, Legend, SimpleRenderer, SimpleMarkerSymbol,
        Color, arrayUtils, parser, InfoTemplate, ClassBreaksRenderer, WFSLayer, LabelLayer, TextSymbol, Font, SimpleLineSymbol, esriConfig
      ) {
        parser.parse();


  esriConfig.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("[:8080");
        var map = new Map("map", [URL]
          basemap: "gray",
   center: [-122.836, 42.346],
   zoom: 13
        });


  var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Attributes", "${*}");
  // initializing layer in this way does not use renderer properly  
  var layer = new WFSLayer(); 
  var opts = {
  "url": "[URL]/geoserver/wfs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "zip_centroids",
  "wkid": 4326,
  "maxFeatures": 100,
  "mode": "snapshot"
  };
  layer.fromJson(opts);
  layer.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
  /* // initializing layer as below works
        var layer = new FeatureLayer("https://tmservices1.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/LiveFeeds/NOAA_METAR_current_wind_speed_direction/MapServer/0", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
          outFields:["*"],
          infoTemplate: infoTemplate
        });
  */
        map.addLayers([layer]);

        var marker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
        var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(marker);


        renderer.setColorInfo({
          field: "temp",
          minDataValue: -20,
          maxDataValue: 296000,
          colors: [
            new Color([0,104,214]), new Color([20,120,220]), new Color([39,136,226]),
            new Color([59,152,232]), new Color([78,169,237]), new Color([98,185,243]),
            new Color([131,197,181]), new Color([164,210,120]), new Color([197,222,58]),
            new Color([205,188,80]), new Color([212,155,102]), new Color([220,121,124]),
            new Color([216,87,115]), new Color([211,53,106]), new Color([206,19,97])
          ]
        });
        layer.setRenderer(renderer);


      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <div id="border-container" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'" style="width: 200px;"><div id="legend"></div></div>
      <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="padding: 0;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What happens is the WFS layer renders only with the default symbol while the native layer renders using the color ramp. (Note: I have added a field to the WFS layer called "TEMP" so that I dont have to change when I toggle betweenthe two example, so that's not why.) Any ideas?

Comment: Shot in the dark: try moving `map.addLayers([layer]);` to right after `layer.setRenderer(renderer);`.

Comment: good guess. I've had that work before. Not this time though.

Comment: In case anyone runs into this, I think its a bug as I never found a solution. I have dual posted it on ESRI's GeoNet and gotten no response in either place. I am going to use a class breaks renderer with quintiles that I generate dynamically instead as there appears to be no solution to this.